# How much space do I need to install an APK of the size of N?

Tags: android, size, apk, storage

I've looked through the following links (and a few more, in fact), but they don't explain how much space I need to install an APK of the size of N.

["Insufficient storage" when trying to install new app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23010/18093)

[In Depth: Android Package Manager and Package Installer](https://dzone.com/articles/depth-android-package-manager)

The app I am going to install is a user app, and it's not downloaded from Google Play. I just download the APK, save it to `/data/data/com.myapp/app_`, and then run the system dialog, and the user confirms the update.

```
private void install() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.fromFile(mApkSaveDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + APK)),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
    );
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think it is possible to do this

APK is a file like RAR or ZIP

it simply compresses files and no more

Size after decompress depends on what files were arhived

There also may be resources

What is actually known is a fact that size after decompress will be more. Usually it looks like 1 to 3